# Why do I see less memory on my Asus tablet then specified?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, ram, 3.2-honeycomb

I have asus eee pad transformer tf101. In application/running I see `195mb used+ 366mb free = 560mb`. But it should be 1 gb by specification!

Then in Quodrant in section memmory I see:

```
Total: 745932 KB
Free:106624 kb
inactive: 256736 Kb
```

Summing them up I get 1109292. btw what does inactive mean?

So why there are different amount of using memory and specified?

Answer (score 4):

An part of the RAM is reserved - often for the GPU - and not useable by the dalvik VM and Apps. This is not uncommon: Samsungs Galaxy S has also 512MB but only 334MB are useable by Apps. This can differ from ROM version to version.